# Would wearing leg weights 24/7 be effective?

Tags: legs, weights

If you were to wear leg weights, say a kilo or more on each leg, and never took them off for a month or so, would your feet get stronger, would that benefit you, or would it give you issues?

*Would it be healthy?*

Answer (score 0):

You would be doing more harm then good because extra strain is placed on joints. This can lead to aching and painful joints and could cause more significant problems that inhibit your ability to walk. Wearing them for a month straight woudn't be a good idea. What are you trying to accomplish? Stronger feet? I have worn ankle weights before and they workout your legs not really your feet. Here is a link to an article that backs up my initial statement. 
http://www.livestrong.com/article/287192-does-wearing-ankle-weights-all-day-make-a-difference/ 
This is assuming you are speaking of ankle weights because you mentioned feet getting stronger. I do not believe I have heard of leg weights....